# "inner" tag needs some cleanup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

There <strike>are</strike> was 110 questions currently tagged with [inner](/questions/tagged/inner). Most of them are either a mistype variant of [inner-classes](/questions/tagged/inner-classes), [inner-join](/questions/tagged/inner-join), etc. but there are also other variant of which I'm not comfortable to edit ([android](/questions/tagged/android), [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) question mainly). If someone could take a look it would be nice.

<strike>Also once, this cleanup is done,</strike> Now, should the [inner](/questions/tagged/inner) tag be burninated to force people to tag their question properly or should we just leave it as it is now ?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the ones which were tagged as inner within other categories were talking about like "inner divs" and other things like that where the tag was completely unnecessary and needed to be removed. Either way, there are now 0 questions tagged [inner](/questions/tagged/inner), it can be deleted. [That was fun.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

---

**Edit:** This doesn't appear to have been recreated in the months it has been destroyed, so burnination doesn't appear to be needed here.